# Cannot create notification in Chrome Extension. Receive Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display a notification in my Chrome extension when an HTTP response is received. Every time I try, I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

I have made sure that I have the notifications permission set in the manifest.json.

I thought I might be able to do the notification in a callback function, however anything I pass in for a callback (function, constant, variable, etc) is always undefined.

Here is my relevant code.

```
function push(info,tab) {
   function modifyDOM(tab_info, callback) {
    var endpoint = "https://blahblahblah";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    alert(callback); //always undefined. 
  
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) { 
            alert(this.responseText); 

             var msg = 'Pushed ' + tab_info.tab.url + ' to endpoint'; 
             var opt = {
                 iconUrl: "images/img48.png",
                 type: 'basic',
                 title: 'Handler',
                 message: msg
               };
               chrome.notifications.create(opt); //Error occurs here. 
          }
          else { 
            alert(callback); //always undefined 
          }
      }
    };
  
    xmlhttp.open("POST", endpoint);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "body": {"content": document.body.innerText }, "query": { "url": tab_info.tab.url, "title": tab_info.tab.title} }));
}

chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '(' + modifyDOM + ')(' + JSON.stringify({ "tab" : tab, "callback": 1}) +');' //callback parameter is always undefined in the modifyDOM() function above 
}, (results) => {
    console.log(results[0]);
  });
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,    
 "version": "1.0",               
 "name": "Handler",   
 "description": "Push to endpoint",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/img16.png",
    "48": "images/img48.png",
    "128": "images/img128.png"
   },
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "*://*/*",
    "notifications"
],
 "background": { 
   "scripts": ["script.js"]
   }
  }
```

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of API so you'll have to do it in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks again for responding. This is a background script. I'll add my manifest.json to the question.

Comment: Setup messaging between you background and content scripts. Then send a message from your content script to instruct your background script to show the notification

Comment: Can you try to do the notification at the top of the script.js, to test if it actually works

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer Yes - That works if I add it below the push() function.

Comment: What about the function in a function and how are these called?

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't think it is that. I reload the extension and clear the console every time I make a change.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer Can you clarify which functions you are referring to? Push() is called from a click event on a context menu, modifyDOM is called by chrome.tabs.executescript.

Comment: Since the notifications work from the top level, go down each level, so first in Push and if that works in modifyDom.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer it works in push() but does not work below that. modifyDOM() generates the error.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I don't think this is a content script though. In my manifest I have this as a background script.

Comment: "This code is injected as a content script" means exactly that. You're injecting it via executeScript and the result is a content script.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer, you just don't know how extensions API works. The API function chrome.tabs.executeScript takes the function's code as a string and injects it as a content script.

Comment: I've already said that the solution is to call chrome.notifications.create in the background script and I thought that's sufficient. I'm not being demeaning, I just state the facts.

Comment: Okay, I guess I should add an answer to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. We clearly don't understand that executeScript makes it so your function are run as content scripts as opposed to background scripts

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem 1

The function `modifyDOM` doesn't **run** inside the background script. It's only declared there and you convert its code into a string and inject via chrome.tabs.executeScript, which runs the code as a content script in the active tab. Content scripts can't use most of `chrome` API, they can use only the few basic ones like chrome.i18n, chrome.runtime, chrome.storage.

The solution is to call chrome.notifications in the background script context e.g. send a message from the injected code.

#### Problem 2

The parameters are passed as a single object `{ "tab" : tab, "callback": 1}` but the function is declared to take two.

The simplest solution is to declare the function to take a single object too and use *destructuring*.

#### Result

```js
function modifyDOM({tab, callback}) {
  // ..............
  xmlhttp.onload = function () {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Pushed ' + tab_info.tab.url + ' to endpoint');
    }
  };
  // ..............
}
```

background script global code:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  var opt = {
    iconUrl: 'images/img48.png',
    type: 'basic',
    title: 'Handler',
    message,
  };
  chrome.notifications.create(opt); 
});
```